# Is there any bluetoothdevice unique id

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want my program to react on when some bluetooth device is on. So i want to know is there any Unique ID of each bluetooth device that can be use to identifiy Bluetooth device via BluetoothDevice android class. I cannot work with device name because there are lot of devices with the same name:
Here is how i got the name:

```
  Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
                String bluetoothDevice = bt.getName();
    }
```

Comment: Often the MAC address, if it is static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [device address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getAddress%28%29):

```
bt.getAddress();
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is unique address for each Bluetooth device?

Comment: It's an industry agreement (same as MAC in ethernet world), so as long as device manufacturer does obey this rule, it should be unique.

Comment: At many devices it is not consistent, permanent and should not be serialized for long term storage. Since many devices change their address every "once in a while" randomly.

Comment: This is not valid anymore since android 6.0. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377982/get-bluetooth-local-mac-address-in-marshmallow/33387430#33387430) link.