# MIT App Inventor 2 obtain own device bluetooth address

Tags: app-inventor

I wanted to obtain the bluetooth MAC address of my android device, which is currently running the app, is there anyway to obtain it?

I am doing a project and I need the app to obtain my own device bluetooth address instead of going to the settings to view it manually.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33387430/1545993): Access to the mac address has been deliberately removed:

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this
>   release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local
>   hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs.

(from [Android 6.0 Changes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id))

For **App Inventor** you could write your own extension and create a block yourself using [this workaround](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html).

More information about how to create an extension see [here](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html).
 However that will be more advanced and will require some Java skills...

Comment: The wifi extension returns a wifi mac address.
Is there any relation to a phone wifi and bluetooth mac address? can i get the bluetooth mac address by manipulating the wifi mac address?

Comment: You are right, my Wifi extension can only provide the Wifi MAC address. To get the Bluetooth MAC address see my updated answer.

Comment: see my new [bluetooth extension](https://puravidaapps.com/bluetooth.php) to get the Bluetooth MAC address