# How to get mobile bluetooth MAC address programmatically in oreo

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to get mobile blue-tooth mac id programmatically.i saw some link and i got this coce.

```
String macAddress = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_address");
```

upto nougat this code is working fine.But i am getting null in OREO(8.0.0) and i gave permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

So is there a way to get the bluetooth mac address in OREO?

Answer (score 2):

The blue-tooth mac address is only available to system apps in Android Oreo. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33387430/5590249) answer for details. Moreover you can also read [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-o-introduces-changes-and-improvements-to-device-identifiers/) article for more information.