# Get Bluetooth local mac address in Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bluetooth

Due to security reason, bluetoothAdapter.getAddress() is returning 02:00:00:00:00:00 from Android Marshmallow.
I try to get from android.provider.Settings.Secure but still fail.
So is there a way to get the local bluetooth mac address?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bluetooth_address = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_address");
    address = findViewById(R.id.address1);
    address.setText(bluetooth_address);
}
```

“I expect the textView will be set as 6B:3E:CB:2E:C4:C7, but the actual output is null.”

Comment: Some good (non-accepted) answers on the linked question!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377982/get-bluetooth-local-mac-address-in-marshmallow

Comment: @stkent I've tried these methods but none of them work...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896816/device-bluetooth-address-in-oreo-8-1
Or to be short - it is not possible so far.