# The android device how to get the bluetooth mac it broadcasts to outer device?

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So,this is my question,I want to know the main device how to get the  bluetooth mac itself.I try to use `adapter.getAddress()` and reflect methods,all kind of ways ets,but no one works right...please do me a favor!

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().startLeScan(callback)

BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice deviceTmp, int rssi,
                         byte[] scanRecord) {

        String strDeviceName = deviceTmp.getName();
        if (strDeviceName != null) {
            Log.i(tag, "action_found , " + deviceTmp.getName()  + "mac = "  + deviceTmp.getAddress());
```

2018年9月4日10:49:15 add new code

```
public static String getBtAddressByReflection() {
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Field field = null;
    try {
        field = BluetoothAdapter.class.getDeclaredField("mService");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object bluetoothManagerService = field.get(bluetoothAdapter);
        if (bluetoothManagerService == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Method method = bluetoothManagerService.getClass().getMethod("getAddress");
        if(method != null) {
            Object obj = method.invoke(bluetoothManagerService);
            if(obj != null) {
                return obj.toString();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What about `getAddress` didn't work?

Comment: I get the  bluetooth mac address by the code above,it's same as the mac show in device's infomation.but it differs from the mac the client scans

Comment: Related: [Get Bluetooth local mac address in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33377982/295004), do read all of the comments